# Custom UICollectionViewLayout, change cell height after image is downloaded inside a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using pinterest tutorial to achieve dynamic cell height according to image's size.

But there is a problem: After it downloaded the data, I send the `URL` to according `cell`. When the cell receives the link, it will download and change the picture. But from the tutorial, it calculate the image size way before its downloaded because it uses temp images that are already stored.

Inside cell Class:

```
var imageURL: String? {
        didSet {
            imageView.loadImage(self.imageURL ?? "")
        }
    }
```

Func to return image size height, this is in the `ViewController` class

```
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return imgArr[indexPath.item].size.height + 100
        // it should be like this
        // guard let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? LoansCell else {return}
        // return cell.photo.size.height

    }
```

Inside the UICollectionViewLayout class:

```
  override func prepare() {
        // 1    
        var section = 1 
        if isPartner {
            section = 0
        }
        let collectionViewItemCount = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section) ?? 0
        guard cache.isEmpty || collectionViewItemCount > cache.count, let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        // 2
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset: [CGFloat] = []
        for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset: [CGFloat] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)
        
        // 3
        for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
            for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                let attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

                // where it calls the protocol to get image h
                let photoHeight = delegate?.collectionView(
                    collectionView,
                    heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath) ?? 180
                let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
                let frame: CGRect
                var paddingForSection0: CGFloat = cellPadding // to make the horizontalView leading and trailling = screen.leading/trailing
                if section == 0 && !isPartner {
                    frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                   y: yOffset[column] + headerHeight + cellPadding,
                                   width: contentWidth + insetLeftRight*2,
                                   height: height)
                    
                    contentHeight = frame.maxY
                    for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
                        yOffset[column] = frame.maxY
                    }
                    paddingForSection0 = 0
                    column = 0
                } else {
                    // 4
                    var yPad = cellPadding * 2
                    if isPartner { // this is a temp approach
                        headerHeight = 0
                        yPad = cellPadding
                    }
                    frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column] + insetLeftRight,
                                   y: yOffset[column] + headerHeight + yPad,
                                   width: columnWidth,
                                   height: height)
                    
                    contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
                    yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
                    column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
                }
                
                let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: paddingForSection0, dy: cellPadding)
                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = insetFrame
                cache.append(attributes)
            }
        }
    }
```

The article I used: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: I think you should start with some default height and then you need to have some listener from when image has finished loading in your cell and adjust the height of the cell after you know the size of the image.

Comment: Hi Frank, thats what i've been doing but I don't know what to call after getting the height of the cell. Even reload cell doesn't work

Comment: After your image has loaded, what if you made a call to invalidate layout - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617728-invalidatelayout - this should ideally call your prepare method again inside your layout class and I am hoping the new height calculations would take place